# Fix and the stabiliser

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ act on $X$, and let $x \in X$ and $g \in G$.

Is $\textrm{fix}(g)$ the same thing as the stabiliser of $x$?

I am inclined to say it is because in my notes it says "Let $x \in \textrm{fix}(g)$. Then $x \wedge g=x$ and the stabiliser of $x$ is the set $G_x=\{g \in G \mid x \wedge g=x\}$."

However, I would like some confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

They are not the same.  Notice $$fix(g) \subset X$$ while $$G_x \subset G.$$  You should note that for any $x \in X$, $G_x$ is a subgroup of $G$, while we are not even guaranteed that $X$ has a group structure.

Answer (score 1):

Using your notation,
$$
\text{Fix}(g) = \{x \in X : x \wedge g = x\}
$$
while
$$
G_x = \{g \in G : x \wedge g = x\} \, .
$$
So, as Brillo says, these are not equal since $\text{Fix}(g)$ is a subset of $X$, while $G_x$ is a subset (actually a subgroup) of $G$.  There is a nice relation however:
$$
x \in \text{Fix}(g) \iff x \wedge g = x \iff g \in G_x
$$
which in words says that $x$ is fixed by $g$ is the same as saying that $g$ stabilizes $x$.